# One of my Android activities work badly

Tags: java, android, webview

Hello dear StackOverflow community!!!
While developing my recent application project i found some problems while debugging the app. In my project i want to pass one data element through 2 activities. Everything looks good (no errors or other stuff) until i choose WatchingActivity in my app. It displays no webview but only white blank space while there should be video choosen in PartActivity. Please help!!!!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String clipname;
    ImageView ka;
    ImageView jb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ka = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        jb = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    }

    public void imageView1Clicked(View view) {
        // method that is signed in layout file to be called by clicking on imageView1
        clipname="Kendra's Adventure";
        Intent mainintent = new Intent(this, ChooseAPartActivity.class);
        mainintent.putExtra("CLIP", clipname);
        startActivity(mainintent);
    }

    public void imageView2Clicked(View view) {
        clipname="Johhny Big";
        Intent mainintent = new Intent(this, ChooseAPartActivity.class);
        mainintent.putExtra("CLIP", clipname);
        startActivity(mainintent);

    }
}

public class ChooseAPartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView title;
    TextView part1;
    TextView part2;
    TextView part3;
    TextView part4;
    TextView part5;
    TextView part6;
    String videoname;
    String partnumber;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_a_part);
        title.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        title.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        Intent mainintent = getIntent();

        String clipname = mainintent.getStringExtra("CLIP");

        title.setText(clipname);
        videoname = clipname;
    }

    public void partone (View view) { 
    //method assigned to textview in layout file
        partnumber = "one";
        Intent partintent = new Intent(this, WatchingActivity.class);
        partintent.putExtra("PART", videoname);
        partintent.putExtra("NUMBER", partnumber);
        startActivity(partintent);
    }
    public void parttwo (View view) {
        partnumber = "two";
        Intent partintent = new Intent(this, WatchingActivity.class);
        partintent.putExtra("PART", videoname);
        partintent.putExtra("NUMBER", partnumber);
        startActivity(partintent);
    }
    public void partthree (View view) {
        partnumber = "three";
        Intent partintent = new Intent(this, WatchingActivity.class);
        partintent.putExtra("PART", videoname);
        partintent.putExtra("NUMBER", partnumber);
        startActivity(partintent);
    }
    public void partfour (View view) {
        partnumber = "four";
        Intent partintent = new Intent(this, WatchingActivity.class);
        partintent.putExtra("PART", videoname);
        partintent.putExtra("NUMBER", partnumber);
        startActivity(partintent);
    }
    public void partfive (View view) {
        partnumber = "five";
        Intent partintent = new Intent(this, WatchingActivity.class);
        partintent.putExtra("PART", videoname);
        partintent.putExtra("NUMBER", partnumber);
        startActivity(partintent);
    }
    public void partsix (View view) {
        partnumber = "six";
        Intent partintent = new Intent(this, WatchingActivity.class);
        partintent.putExtra("PART", videoname);
        partintent.putExtra("NUMBER", partnumber);
        startActivity(partintent);
    }
}
public class WatchingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String clipkey;
    WebView screen;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_watching);
Intent sceneintent = getIntent();

        String videoname = partintent.getStringExtra("PART");
        String partnumber = sceneintent.getStringExtra("NUMBER");

        if(videoname == "Kendra's Adventure"){
            if(partnumber == "one"){
         clipkey = "<iframe width=\"95%\" height=\"95%\" src=\"links work fine i tried it many times so its not that\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
            }
        }
        else if(videoname == "Johnny Big"){
            if(partnumber == "one") {
                clipkey = "<iframe width=\"95%\" height=\"95%\" src=\"\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
            }
            else if(partnumber == "two"){
                clipkey = "<iframe width=\"95%\" height=\"95%\" src=\"\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";

            }
        }
        screen=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        screen.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        String myvideokey = clipkey;
        screen.loadData(myvideokey, "text/html", "utf-8");
        screen.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
        });
}
}
```

Comment: `videoname.equals("Kendra's Adventure")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Don't use == to compare String, use String.equals()

Comment: I'd also suggest you to check if iframe is going to work with Android webviews

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Answer (score 0):

```
String videoname = partintent.getStringExtra("PART");
```

Is that line ok in WatchingActivity? There is no partintent field or something.

Defining all activities in the same class-file is not really good idea.

Comment: it's `public` so not the case

Comment: So, I don't know whre it's received from. Right way is to pass such data from and activity-starting intent and later receive it with getIntent() method

Comment: yup you are right , in both cases there should be a compile time error or OP just simply forget that part